# Creating ticket with attachment in Freshdesk

Tags: python, json, odoo, python-requests, freshdesk

I want to create a ticket with attachment in freshdesk api. I am able to create a ticket without attachment. This is my sample code:

```
post_dict = {
    'helpdesk_ticket': {
        'description': "Testing Code sample 3",
        'subject': "example7",
        'email': "example7@example.com",
        'priority': 2,
        'status': 2,
    },
}

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(FRESHDESK_URL + '/helpdesk/tickets.json',
        auth=(FRESHDESK_API_KEY, "X"),
        headers=headers,
        data=json.dumps(post_dict),
        )

raw_input(r.status_code)
raw_input(r.content)
```

This is for just creating ticket in Freshdesk. Now using the same post_dict i would like to create tickets with attachments. Any suggestions about how I can achieve this using this json request method or any other methods are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a ticket with an attachment requires a multi-part form submission. Unfortunately that means that the request is very different to a simple request without an attachment.

Each field needs to be written to the request as a separate form with a 'boundary' before it and a character return after it.

Then, each attachment should be written to the request, again with a boundary before the attachment is written and a character return added after.

At the end of the response, a final boundary must be written. This is the same as the string used for the boundary but also includes 2 dashes ( -- ) before and after the boundary to signify it as final. Without the final boundary, FreshDesk gives a 500 internal server error since something changed in their api a few weeks back (it used to accept a non-final boundary at the end).

Answer (score 0):

For Send attachment, the  Content-Type must be in `multipart/form-data`.The sample cURL is may helps you.

```
curl -v -u yourmail@gmail.com:yourpassword -F 
"attachments[]=@/path/to/attachment1.ext" -F     
"attachments[]=@/path/to/attachment2.ext" -F "email=example@example.com" -F     
"subject=Ticket Title" -F "description=this is a sample ticket" -X POST 
'https://yoururl.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets'
```